# Деление сети на VLAN

Tags: сеть, подсети, vlan

Предположим сложилась такая ситуация. На предприятии есть два модема которые раздают интернет. Один для администрации на первом этаже, другой для прочего персонала на втором.
Адрес 1-го модема: 192.168.100.1
                   255.255.255.0 
Адрес 2-го модема: 192.168.0.1
                   255.255.255.0
Оба в Route, DHCP отключен.
Планируется объединить сети. Есть коммутатор D-Link L3.
Возможно ли подключить к коммутатору два модема оставив им те же адреса.Создать два Vlan. На Vlan1 забить первый модем и администрацию, а на Valn2 второй модем и прочий персонал, так чтобы у каждой группы был свой интернет и они не видели друг друга.
P.S. извиняйте если криво объяснил.

Comment: Собственно VLAN в основном и используется для решения подобных задач. С точки зрения внешнего наблюдателя всё выглядит так, словно коммутатор разделен на два независимых коммутатора, каждый из которых обслуживает только свой VLAN. Вам потребуется три VLAN - для администрации, для персонала, и для управления коммутатором (управляющим VLAN можно, конечно, сделать один из пользовательских, но не рекомендую привыкать к плохому). Поскольку коммутатор один, все порты всех VLAN будут non-tagged.

Comment: Спасибо.Будем пробовать.